# What is wrong with my R code, it doesn't give expected output

Tags: r, database

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhz1d.png)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ4Yp.png)

The picture on the top is my code with output, but the output of histogram is not correct compare to the second picture (the y-axis part)

Comment: Don't send your code as image, please. It's not helpful.

Comment: Looks like you're using too many bins. There are 10 in the output. That's the only difference I see. For future reference it's preferable to use code blocks to provide code instead of images :)

Comment: Please include data, code and result in your post as text, if possible (clearly not applicable for figures).

Answer (score 0):

Your number of bins doesn't meet the requested.

Increasing/decreasing the number of bins leads to the change of `x margin` value that will be used to calculate the distribution.

Try with `bins = 10` and you'll get the same picture (probability = 99.9%).

If not, you're probably using dataset with different values that in the example.